# Check if entire array of characters in C are only numbers, return true if yes?

Tags: c

I have a string array of numbers:

```
char numbers[5][10] = { "123456789", "0001234", "abc5xyz", "", "987654321" };
```

I pass this array to a function:

```
  for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
     MyFNatoi(numbers[i], &value);
     printf("array: '%s' int value: %d\n", numbers[i], value);
  }
```

In this function, how could I check if the entire string is only numbers and return true if so? So far all I have is:

```
MyFNatoi(char *numArray, int *value) {

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (numArray[i] > 47 && numArray[i] < 58) {
            printf("%c", numArray[i] - 0);
            // sscanf(p, "%d", &value);
        }
    }
}
```

And that just returns:

```
123456789array: '123456789' int value: -1217188485
0001234array: '0001234' int value: -1217188485
5array: 'abc5xyz' int value: -1217188485
array: '' int value: -1217188485
987654321array: '987654321' int value: -1217188485
```

I'm trying to get value variable to be the equivalent of the string. So if the string is `123456789`, `value` should be `123456789`. If it is `abc5xyz`, `value` should be `0`.

So far it just converts the characters to a 0 and returns :(

**full source**

```
#include <stdio.h>

MyFNatoi(char *numArray, int *value) {

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (numArray[i] > 47 && numArray[i] < 58) {
            printf("%c", numArray[i] - 0);
            // sscanf(p, "%d", &value);
        }

        // printf("%c", numArray[i]);
    }
// printf("- ");
}

int main( ) {

      char numbers[5][10] = { "123456789", "0001234", "abc5xyz", "", "987654321" };
      int i, value;

      for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
         MyFNatoi(numbers[i], &value);
         printf("array: '%s' int value: %d\n", numbers[i], value);
      }

      return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `for` loop in `MyFNatoi()` should be based on the length of `numArray` rather than the size of the array: use `strlen(numArray)` and not `10`.

Use `isdigit()` to determine if a character is a digit or not.

If all the characters were digits then assign `*value` to `atoi()`. Otherwise, set `*value` to `0`:

```
void MyFNatoi(char *numArray, int *value)
{
    int i;
    const int len = strlen(numArray);

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        /* #include <ctype.h> for 'isdigit()'. */
        if (!isdigit(numArray[i])) break;
    }
    /* #include <stdlib.h> for 'atoi()'. */
    *value = len == i ? atoi(numArray) : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't set `*value` to 0 to indicate failure - 0 is a valid integer.  Use the return value instead, as you indicate in the body of the text.  Use the standard library rather than loop yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* return true on success */
int MyFNatoi(const char *numArray, int *value)
{
    int n = 0;
    return sscanf(numArray, "%d%n", value, &n) > 0 /* integer was converted */
       &&  numArray[n] == '\0'; /* all input got consumed */
}
```

Comment: @eveo; note that spaces, here, does not disqualify number. Often what one want, but even so/good to know. Also numbers > INT_MAX is truncated to INT_MAX (and numbers < INT_MIN to INT_MIN). Beside that, yes, for the love of C, use return value on such a function.